# How can you use googlemock on a method which takes Eigen::Tensor objects as input parameters?

Tags: c++, eigen, googletest, googlemock, eigen3

I have a class as following:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    void my_method(Eigen::Tensor<double, 5> &param);
};
```

I would like to create a mock:

```
class MockMyClass {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, my_method, (Eigen::Tensor<double, 5>), (override));
};
```

But I get the error

`static assertion failed: This method does not take 2 arguments. Parenthesize all types with unproctected commas.`

because of the comma in the Tensor type declaration `<double, 5>`. Is there a recommended way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation states](https://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#dealing-with-unprotected-commas), types can't have unprotected commas or else it won't compile (due to the way these macros are implemented). There are two options to work around that:

1. Wrap each type with comma in another set of parentheses:

```
    MOCK_METHOD(void, my_method, ((Eigen::Tensor<double, 5>&)), (override));
```

2. Use a type alias:

```
    using TensorType = Eigen::Tensor<double, 5>;
    MOCK_METHOD(void, my_method, (TensorType&), (override));
```

Comment: When I try to use your suggestion with the double parenthesis, I now get the error `‘testing::internal::Function<void(Eigen::Tensor<double, 5>&)>::Result MockMyClass::my_method(testing::internal::ElemFromListImpl<Eigen::Tensor<double, 5>&, 0, 0>::type)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override`

Comment: @Yes Because your original function is not `virtual`. Compiler is very much right to warn you - you specifically asked it to check if function overrides, and it doesn't.